# Email sending error: magento 2 Warning: Illegal string offset 'frontend_name' in vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php on line 465

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.4

I am sending an email in custom event, it was working fine in Magento 2.3.1 but after upgrade to Magento version 2.4.0, It's showing me an error when I sending an email from custom code. Below is the code sample.

```
 $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $options[$customer->getWebsiteId()]);


        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $store->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getName(),
            'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
            'name' => $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname(),
            'newGroup' => $newGroupName,
            'oldGroup' => $oldGroupName,
            'logo_alt' => $logo['logo_alt'],
            'logo_width' => $logo['logo_width'],
            'logo_height' => $logo['logo_height'],
            'support_email' => $sender['email'],
            'support_phone' => $phone,
            'logo_url' => $store->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . 'email/logo/' . $logo['logo'],
        );

        $from = array('email' => $storeEmail, 'name' => $storeName);
        $to = array($customer->getEmail());

        $transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('customer_change_group_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Below is the Magento 2 Warning:

```
Illegal string offset 'frontend_name' in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php on line 465
```

I checked the above file for error and found below the line on 465, if I commented then it's working

```
if (!isset($variables['store']['frontend_name'])) {
            $variables['store']['frontend_name'] = $store->getFrontendName();
        }
```

I don't know what is use of this code in email sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by change store as storename in param

```
$templateVars = array(
    'storeName' => $store->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getName(),
    'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
    'name' => $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname(),
    'logo_alt' => $logo['logo_alt'],
    'logo_width' => $logo['logo_width'],
    'logo_height' => $logo['logo_height'],
    'support_email' => $sender['email'],
    'support_phone' => $phone,
    'logo_url' => $store->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
        ) . 'email/logo/' . $logo['logo'],
);
```